# How to store null value document in couchbase with java client v3?

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api, couchbase-java-client

I have a java couchbase client v2 that saves documents to database

```java
JsonObject content = ...
JsonDocument newDocument = JsonDocument.create(key, expiration, content);
bucket.upsert(newDocument);
```

When `content` is `null` it saves a 'null-value' document that looks in the couchbase console like this

[image]

I'm migrating to couchbase java client v3 and save the document next way

```java
JsonObject content = ...
var upsertOptions = UpsertOptions.upsertOptions();
if (expiration != null) {
    upsertOptions.expiry(expiration);
}
bucket.defaultCollection().upsert(key, content, upsertOptions);
```

`JsonDocument` is not available in v3 and I put `JsonObject` directly and it works OK when `content` is not `null`.

When I have `content` as `null` like a previous case it throws an exception `com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException`. If I try to use `JsonObject.create()` instead of `null` it creates an empty document but not 'null-value' document

[image]

Is it possible to create the same 'null-value' document with a client v3 for the sake of backward compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Couchbase Java SDK 3.x, here's one way to store a JSON document with a null at the root:

```java
collection.upsert(key, "null", UpsertOptions.upsertOptions()
    .transcoder(RawJsonTranscoder.INSTANCE));
```

It uses [RawJsonTranscoder](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/3.2/howtos/transcoders-nonjson.html#rawjsontranscoder) which interprets the content as pre-serialized JSON.

Comment: It's not evident but it works! Thanks for help